# Toggling preview tab for pydoc

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

I am new to VIM and I had this happened on few occasions. I am using these plug-ins:

- nerdcommenter-master
- vim-autoclose-master
- vim-multiple-cursors-master
- nerdtree-master
- vim-autocomplpop

Sometimes I am typing python commands and autocomplete comes up, and I accidentally hit something. This new tab pop-ups with help text, describing the autocompleted command, basically like using `pydoc`. I'd like to know what this is called and how can I invoke it (I find it very useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the *omni completion* from the Python filetype plugin that ships with Vim, in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim`. It is automatically triggered by the AutoComplPop plugin. You can also explicitly invoke it by pressing `<C-x><C-o>` in insert mode; `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O`.

The preview comes courtesy of `:set completeopt+=preview`.

Comment: nice thank you.. I just couldn't google it anywhere. is there a way for the window to close automatically once I'm done inserting commands?

Comment: Maybe `:autocmd CompleteDone * pclose`?!